# How to create FTP user with specific directory access in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, ssh, ftp

I want to create many FTP user associating with specific directory and it should be using PHP in Laravel. 
How can I do this? Is it possible to do?

I think the following code can create directory and user,

```
1 mkdir /var/www/mydomain.com/html
2. useradd <-username>
3. passwrd <-username>
4. chown –R <-username> /var/www/mydomain.com
```

Is there any library in Laravel or PHP function to execute SSH command?

Answer (score 0):

[`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) does the job. If you need to do it on a remote, consider using envoy:

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/envoy

or for L4.2:

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ssh

Either way, be very careful when exposing shell commands to a web service. *Especially* when using commands intended for super users (`useradd`, `usermod`, `passwd` etc.). At the very least, limit the users `sudo`-rights to the minimum set of commands needed to do what you're trying to do. Things could potentially go very wrong if you don't know what you're doing (specifically I'm thinking shell injections).

Comment: Dear, I want to do it when a user signup with my application then he actually get FTP user, word and directory dynamically.

Comment: If it's on the server running the application, use `exec` to execute shell scripts (What you'd normally do if you were creating it manually). **Be sure** to use [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) if you're using **any** user provided input (even their username). If it's on another server than the one running your app, use envoy or ssh (the links I provided in the answer).